# Add required libraries to build from CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-cdt

In a project I am working on I depend on a couple of external libraries that are necessary for the program to run. On my local machine they can be found in usr/local/lib and everything works like a charm.

Now, when I build my Release I want these libraries to be added to the build
(I want to end up with my executable and all necessary libs) and configure it, such that when I run the program from commandline, it knows the libraries are in lib.

I could manually add all the libraries in this folder on my local machine and configure my project so that it can find the libraries here, but, even using variables, it still inserts a local path, so using it on other machines does not work. Or is there a way to do this starting from the project path?

Is this possible using CDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use relative paths to the project folder, that should be totally portable, as long as the other machines can run such libraries. For example if your project is in `/home/Fristi/project`, you could just copy all your static libraries into `./libs` (which actually points to `/home/Fristi/project/libs` and add `./libs` in your makefile or CDT configuration.